# re-list machines on docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I created several instances with the docker-machine, but now I changed my host and would like to "import" the machines already created previously. That is, how do I get in this new host I can list the machine already created using "docker-machine ls"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Machine stores it's machine data in `~/.docker/machine`

The `docker-machine` utility [doesn't have in built support for import and export](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/23).

There are [3rd party utilities that can do import/export](https://github.com/bhurlow/machine-share).